# Rounded Corners Outlook & Co

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, newsletter, email-client

I am asking myself if there is a 2022/23 Solution for the problem with rounded corners in Outlook and all the email Clients.

[The latest solution i found](https://kontent.ai/blog/emails-outlook-containers-rounded-courners/).

Sadly, its not realy supported in every Client. I know, support for every Client is quiet difficult, but the Solution is really buggy sometimes.

I wonder if there are new approaches to solve the problem?

I tried the solution above but it´s really buggy.

Answer (score 0):

`border-radius` has very good support across email clients nowadays. (See [Can I email](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-border-radius/)). For Outlook on Windows, VML is still the way to go. But I would usually recommend to let things gracefully degrade instead (meaning you’ll get square corners).

Answer (score 0):

There are VML solutions that make you duplicate the `<a>` link, which is not safe. I found this the other day that lets you keep just one `<a>`, and there is a generator.

This goes in the `<head>`, to help with Windows Mail dark mode for full colour background buttons:

```
<!--[if mso]> 
<style> 
.buttonlink {background: transparent !important;} 
</style> 
<![endif]-->
```

This is the button itself, at full radius (for small corners or different sizes see the generator https://vml-pather.glitch.me/?shape=button):

```
<!--[if mso]>
<v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" style="height:50px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="50%" stroke="false" fillcolor="#3D35FF">
<w:anchorlock/>
<center style="">
<![endif]-->
  <a href="https://www.google.com" style="background-color:#3D35FF;border-radius:25px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:arial, sans-serif;font-size: 20px; line-height: 50px;font-weight: bold;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" class="buttonlink">
    CTA Here
  </a>
<!--[if mso]>
</center>
</v:roundrect>
<![endif]-->
```

Keep in mind the width on mobiles (rule of thumb 300px aim for), not to make the button width too long.